# added build pack and it's not showing up

Tags: python, heroku, phantomjs

I'm trying to use Heroku buildpacks to allow me to run PhantomJS from a Flask app.  I've tried to follow the advice [here](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs) and after I add the buildpacks and push, I still only see `heroku/python` when I check with `heroku buidpacks` at the command line.

After some research it seemed maybe multiple buildpacks is not supported and I needed to try what [this site](http://isaacjohnwesley.tumblr.com/post/57439869677/setting-up-phantomjs-in-heroku-for-your-python-app) recommended.  I added the

```
$ heroku config:
 add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

created the .buildpacks file in the project root with the following:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs
```

and modified the path, as recommended:

```
$ heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/app/vendor/phantomjs/lib
```

after pushing, still I see only `heroku/python` when i try `heroku buildpacks`.

Also, for what it's worth the below test doesn't work for me, because there is no vendor directory.  I'm not sure where that directory even comes from, but it was never in my project, so I can only assume that the buildpacks are suppose to create it?  I found countless references to this directory, and adding this directory to the Heroku path, but not a single one explained it's origin, other than to say that is where the phantomJS buidpack installs to

```
$ heroku run bash
$ vendor/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets stuck on this...

**Rather than this:**

```
$ heroku config:
  add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

**You actually need to do the this:** (as outlined [*here*](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi)):

```
$ heroku buildpacks:
  set https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```